# Strange empty space under ListBox control

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to add `ListBox` control that should fit the whole form. So I set the `Dock` attribute to `Fill`. This is how it looks in Designer:

[image]

And this is how it looks in run-time:

[image]

What is this empty space under ListBox supposed to be for? How can I remove it?

Comment: Border setting maybe ?

Comment: [Integral height](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.integralheight.aspx).

Comment: You probably have IntegralHeight = true; So the size is reduced to show only full items with the given item height ie font size. Hard to advise how to fix it in a way that will work dpi independently.. Obviously the first idea is to make the form a little larger..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set IntegralHeigh = false in property window or in your code

> [**ListBox.IntegralHeight Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.integralheight(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control should resize to
>   avoid showing partial items.
>
> When this property is set to true, the control automatically resizes
>   to ensure that an item is not partially displayed. If you want to
>   maintain the original size of the ListBox based on the space
>   requirements of your form, set this property to false.
>
> By default, the ListBox and the CheckedListBox sizes are such that
>   they show only whole items. If you want the ListBox or CheckedListBox
>   to completely fill a docked area, set IntegralHeight to false. This
>   causes the control to completely fill the area, but the last item is
>   not fully displayed.
>
> If the ListBox does not contain any items, this property has no
>   effect.